# Retrofit response.body() is null when http code is 200

Tags: android, retrofit, response

I can post my object and status code is 200 but response.body() is null. Why is this null ? While i send the data Barcode is empty. when returns barcode must has a value. Because I need to return value. How can i get the return value ?
Thank you.

This is my object.

**EtiketItemPostModel :**

```
public class EtiketItemPostModel { 

     List<EtiketItemModels> EtiketItemModels;
    private String FaturaNo;
    private String Barkod;

     EtiketItemPostModel(List<EtiketItemModels> EtiketItemModels, String 
     FaturaNo,String Barkod) {
        this.FaturaNo = FaturaNo;
        this.EtiketItemModels = EtiketItemModels;
        this.Barkod= Barkod;
    }
    public String getFaturaNo() {
        return FaturaNo;
    }
    public List<EtiketItemModels> getEtiketItem_models() {
        return EtiketItemModels;
    }
    public String getBarkod(){
         return Barkod;
    }
}
```

**EtiketItemModels :**

```
public class EtiketItemModels {

    String StokKodu;
    String StokAdi;
    String Unit;
    double Qtty;
    public EtiketItemModels(String StokKodu, String StokAdi, String Unit, 
       double Qtty) {
        this.StokKodu = StokKodu;
        this.StokAdi = StokAdi;
        this.Unit = Unit;
        this.Qtty = Qtty;
    }
    public String getStokKodu() {
        return StokKodu;
    }
    public String getStokAdi() {
        return StokAdi;
    }
    public String getUnit() {
        return Unit;
    }
    public double getQtty() {
        return Qtty;
    }
}
```

**Interface :**

```
public interface Etiket_Post {
    @POST("api/r_etiket")
     Call<EtiketItemPostModel> post_etiket(@Body EtiketItemPostModel items);
}
```

**Retrofit Call :**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("myURL")                        
                        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                Etiket_Post etiket_post = retrofit.create(Etiket_Post.class);
                ArrayList<EtiketItemModels> items = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int e = 0; e < okutulan_list.size(); e++) {
                    items.add(new EtiketItemModels(
                            okutulan_list.get(e).STOK_KODU,
                            okutulan_list.get(e).STOK_ADI,
                            okutulan_list.get(e).OlcuBrim,
                            okutulan_list.get(e).STHAR_GCMIK));
                }
                String faturano = FileId;
                EtiketItemPostModel etiketPostClass = new EtiketItemPostModel(items, FileId, "");
                Call<EtiketItemPostModel> call = etiket_post.post_etiket(etiketPostClass);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<EtiketItemPostModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<EtiketItemPostModel> call, Response<EtiketItemPostModel> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            String test = response.body().getBarkod();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<EtiketItemPostModel> call, Throwable t) {
                        String tesT = t.getMessage();

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please post what response you get on postman.

Comment: {
"EtiketItemPostModel":{
"EtiketItemModels": ....,
"FaturaNo": .....,
"Barkod": "xxx."
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I changed my interface class. I called an `Object` but return value was a `String`. I expected that a string value so my new interface class is:

```
@POST("api/r_etiket")
Call<String> post_etiket(@Body EtiketItemPostModel items);
```